# Hosting an existing Wordpress installation on a Vagrant box

Tags: wordpress, nginx, vagrant

I have taken over the development of a few websites and am currently trying to get one hosted within a Vagrant box. I am very familiar with Vagrant but am having a strange issue that I have been unable to fix since last Friday.

I have created the Vagrant file and MYSQL database for the Wordpress installation has been moved to my local (host) machine and I point to this from the Wordpress installation on the guest machine. All the Wordpress files exist and the folder is being shared with the guest machine.

My Vagrant file looks as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

# Set Vagrant box to use
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

# Configure port forwarding
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8930, auto_correct: true

# Set synched folder
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", create: true, group: "www-data", owner: "www-data"

# Configure the VM
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "St. David's Lab"
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
end

# Set up shell provisioning
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
```

end

The boostrap.sh file is used to setup the required software and similar on the guest machine and looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Provisioning virtual machine..."
apt-get update

echo "Installing Git"
apt-get install git -y > /dev/null

echo "Installing Nginx"
apt-get install nginx -y >/dev/null

echo "Configuring Nginx"
cp /var/www/nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_vhost > /dev/null

ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_vhost /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx_vhost

rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

service nginx restart > /dev/null

echo "Updating PHP repository"
apt-get install python-software-properties build-essential -y > /dev/null
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5 -y > /dev/null
apt-get update > /dev/null

echo "Installing PHP"
apt-get install php5-common php5-dev php5-cli php5-fpm -y > /dev/null

echo "Installing PHP extensions"
apt-get install curl php5-curl php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mysql -y > /dev/null
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

And here is the server config that gets created on the guest machine:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/;
    index index.php index.html;

    # Important for VirtualBox
    sendfile off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~* \.php {
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_cache off;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

I have changed the siteurl in the Wordpress database to localhost:8930 as well.

The issue I am having is that when I try and access the address localhost:8930 (as defined in the port forwarding in my Vagrant file) I get redirected back to localhost default index page (http://localhost). It is not a cache issue as I have cleared this, used an incognito window and replaced the index file with a simple "hello world" and it shows.

Can anyone see why this may be happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$uri/` clause of the `try_files` directive is causing an external redirect to the default port. You probably want to avoid external redirects from `nginx` itself, because it over complicates your 8930 port mapping rule.

One solution is to remove the `index` directive and the `$uri/` clause.

You really need to add a default controller for WordPress anyway, something like:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```

EDIT:

Detailed analysis of the problem:

You present the URL `http://localhost:8930` which is presented to `nginx` as `http://localhost:80`. The location `/` processes the request. The `try_files` directive tests for the existence of a file and a directory. The presence of a directory causes an external redirect to `http://localhost:80/`. The external redirect is an undocumented side-effect of the `$uri/` clause.

The `try_files` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Could you explain a bit more what that 'location/ try_files) line was doing? I understand most of that file apart from what that does there. I replaced the location line with your suggested one and I still have the same issue. Is there anything else that needs to change? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @devoncrazylegs I have edited the answer. You must restart `nginx` for configuration changes to take effect (and I assume you are continuing to test using `incognito`). Have you changed *both* SITEURL and HOME in WordPress (otherwise the problem may have shifted from `nginx` to WordPress and only *appears* to be the same problem. Finally - you might want to improve your PHP location block - see [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) and [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).